# Getting all orders, where the last order ist older than a year in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table, which holds:
CustomerId and OrderDate

There can me multiple rows for one CustomerId
Now, I try to get the CustomerId's where only the last OrderDate is older than a year.
I try the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM order 
WHERE OrderDate <=DATE_SUB(now(), Interval 1 Year) 
GROUP BY CustomerId 
ORDER BY OrderDate DESCC;
```

The problem here is, that I get all the rows, which are older then 1 year.
But as I said above, I try to get only the latest order, which is older than 1 year.
THX for any advise

Comment: Did you try order by and then limit 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THX for all your tips.
At the end, I found my working solution:

```
    SELECT
  *
FROM order a1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
                order.Id
              FROM (SELECT
                      *
                    FROM (SELECT 
                          * 
                          FROM order 
                          WHERE OrderDate <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 year) 
                            ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) AS Sub
                          GROUP BY Sub.CustomerId) AS a2) AS a3
    ON a1.id = a3.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Order the rows and limit to the last. Also, you had DESCC instead of DESC.

```
SELECT * 
FROM order 
WHERE OrderDate <=DATE_SUB(now(), Interval 1 Year) 
GROUP BY CustomerId 
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You might also try this query:

```
SELECT 
    `CustomerId`,
    `CustomerName`, //  Add other fields you want returned.
    MAX(`OrderDate`)
FROM `order` 
WHERE `OrderDate` <= DATE_SUB(now(), Interval 1 Year) 
GROUP BY `CustomerId` 
ORDER BY MAX(`OrderDate`) DESC;
```

Also, this will return all of the related columns in the last order for each customer:

```
SELECT *
FROM `order` a
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        `CustomerId`,
        MAX(`OrderDate`) as `maxdate`
    FROM `order` 
    WHERE `OrderDate` <= DATE_SUB(now(), Interval 1 Year) 
    GROUP BY `CustomerId`) b
ON a.`CustomerId` = b.`CustomerId` AND
    a.`OrderDate` = b.`maxdate`
ORDER BY `maxdate` DESC;
```

Comment: THX, you are right, I have had a wrong spelling with DESC,
But your query has one problem: The limit will be given to the complete statement. So I will always just get one result, not all orders.

Comment: I found an other solution. But not sure, if it is correct.
In my case I also get only one single result, what I don't think is right...

SELECT
  *
FROM order a1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
      Id
    FROM order
    WHERE OrderDate <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 year)
    GROUP BY CustomerId
    ORDER BY OrderDate DESC LIMIT 1) a2
    ON a1.id = a2.id;

Comment: If you want all orders older than one year, simply remove the LIMIT. If you want the last order for each customer that is older than one year, that can also be done, but wasn't apparent in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this subquery:

`select customer_id 
from customer table 
where order_id in(Select order_id from (select order_id from order_table (year(now())-year(order_date)) = 1 order by order_date desc limit 1))`

if it doesn't work please post your table structure.

Comment: THX for your query. It looks really good.
But I have a big problem. My server version = 5.5.28 and there I am getting the error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: then try this: `select customer_id 
from customer table 
where order_id in(Select order_id from (select order_id from order_table (year(now())-year(order_date)) = 1 order by order_date desc limit 1))`

Comment: apparently mysql doesn't allow limit statement directly in subquery so you have to fool it.